# get value of select box without submitting a form

Tags: php, html, mysql

hi i want to get the value the user selected from the dropdown menu without submitting a form and save it in a php variable any ideas ??

```
<select name="car" value="Select" size="1">

<?php
$sql = "SELECT fullname FROM users"; 

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()); 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

    {
            $name=$row["fullname"]; 
            $options .= '<option value="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</option>';
    }

?>


<?php echo $options; ?>
</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Js and ajax seems right here

Comment: can u please tell me how?

Comment: Have you used js before?

Comment: yes of course i used it

Comment: Then look at Jeffreys answer - he got it covered! :-)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you fully understand how PHP works server side, but to get the value of a dropdown menu without submitting it you'll need Javascript ([jQuery](http://jquery.com/) makes everything easier). From there you just send an [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request using [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) as data format and retrieve it from PHP with [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).